# mvvm cant load the text file .net maui

Tags: .net, mvvm, maui

[[[ente[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tEZP.png)r image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQMGX.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/558eJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urcFy.png)
The mvvm does not load the text file.
i suppuse that the problem is becouse of my Viewmodel.

Hello,
i recently started learning mvvm in.net maui and came across this problem.
i want a file to appear as description, but for some reason its not appearing.

Can you give me some tipps please

Comment: Please don't post code and exceptions as images, always use text and code formatting. Please update your question so that it's readable and understandable. What exactly is the problem and what have you tried already? "The MVVM does not load..." is **not** a problem description, because that's wrong in itself. MVVM is pattern and not a component. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the name of your maui asset file should be `ForMaui.txt` instead of `ForMaui.txt 3`. And then you should set the build action of the load text to `MauiAsset`.

You can use the code below to load from a txt file:

```
try
{
      Stream fileStream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("ForMaui.txt");
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
      bbb= reader.ReadToEnd();
     
}
catch (Exception e)
{
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Comment: There's a lot more wrong with the code than the filename. The OP should first update the question, though.